# python 2.7.10 issues about import bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I installed bs4 successfully but when I import it, the command line told me that

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 303, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser 
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bs4\_htmlparser.py", line 36, in <module>
    from bs4.builder import (
ImportError: No module named builder
```

I have searched google but I didn't find a solution..
Could our experts help me on this issue ?

thanks a lot !

my system info:
PC OS : windows 7 64bit
Python version: 2.7.10

Comment: How did you have installed bs4? using Pip or by using Source Files?

Comment: @imAGin Yes, I intalled bs4 firstly and it returned the package was successfully installed..

Answer (score 0):

You must first `pip install beautifulsoup4`, then try `import bs4`.  If this doesn't work odds are you have a messed up pip configuration.  In order to remedy this either reinstall pip, use easy_install or build from source.

In order to use easy_install just run `easy_install beautifulsoup4`. In order to build from source run download and extract [this zip](https://github.com/getanewsletter/BeautifulSoup4/archive/master.zip) (`unzip /path/to/beautifulsoup4.zip` if you're at the terminal).  Next `cd` into the now unzipped folder by doing `cd /path/to/beautifulsoup` and run `python setup.py`.  The package will now be installed and ready to import!

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled bs4 package and re-installed it. and now it works...

It is quite weird because I tried to uninstall and re-install, but only this time, it worked...

Thanks for your kind help :)